# dotnet new gitignore not creating .gitignore file

Tags: .net, git, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2019

I am trying to create `.gitignore` in NuGet Package Manager Console,
but I find no `.gitignore` shown in the Visual Studio and the root folder.

```
> dotnet new gitignore

Getting ready...
The template "dotnet gitignore file" was created successfully.


> ls

my_server
my_server.sln


> dotnet new gitignore

Creating this template will make changes to existing files:
  Overwrite   .gitignore
```

Comment: It happens because in Linux dot-prefixed folders/files considered hidden. To see created file use `ls -a`, it will show all files, including hidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Figured it out.

Right click your solution in Visual Studio > Display Options > Select `Show all files`

.gitignore will then appear

Answer (score 1):

I also tried same command : dotnet new gitignore
and I successfully created .gitignore file
but you can not see by : ls command
you can go to inside that folder where you run this command :  dotnet new gitignore
you will find .gitignore file is present there don't worry.
it will work fine.
: ls command can't find with '.extension' file it should have file name to find file name.

to see .gitignore   file you should use : ls -a command to see .gitignore  file

Comment: is it possible to view/modify it in visual studio?

Comment: In visual studio open terminal that may be footer area. And then type command : ls -a    you should see your desired output there too. if  this command will not work you need to install git bash. this command will work on git bash or linux terminal.